# Store FOR XML result in xml variable (using WITH statement)

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml

I am creating xml with a SQL query that works like this: First a CTE, then the `SELECT` statement that creates the XML.

That works. However I would like to store the output in a XML variable (a table variable is also ok if that's easier). But I can't seem to get it to work (see second snippet). Any suggestions?

The XML generation that works:

```
;WITH cte
       AS (SELECT ...
          )
  SELECT ...
  FOR XML PATH ('root')
```

This was my attempt to store it in a table variable, but I couldn't get it to work:

```
DECLARE @myXml TABLE(
    x xml
);
;WITH cte
       AS (SELECT ...
          )
  INSERT INTO @myXml SELECT ...
  FOR XML PATH ('root')
```

This is the resulting error message:

> Meldung 6819, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 240
>   Die FOR XML-Klausel ist in einer INSERT-Anweisung nicht zulässig.

(I can't use FOR XML in an insert statement.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put the assignment after the CTE declaration(s).

```
declare @X xml;

with C as
(
  select 1 as X, 2 as Y
)
select @X = 
  (
  select *
  from C
  for xml path('root')
  );
```

If you want the XML to end up in a table variable it would look like this.

```
declare @T table (X xml);

with C as
(
  select 1 as X, 2 as Y
)
insert into @T(X)
select (
       select *
       from C
       for xml path('root')
       );
```

Comment: Please notice that he's using a table variable. He needs to insert into his table this aux @x variable :-).

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson Thanks Mikael, great answer!